# Google Maps API V3 plot address

Tags: javascript, google-maps-api-3, coffeescript

Does any one know any "work arounds" to be able to plot a marker using an address?  We were using geocoding but we have hit limits, and don't really want to add the overhead that is required to store the lat long for an address or zip.

Suggestions?

```
#default lat long
latlng = new google.maps.LatLng(37.662285,-77.57600)

map = new google.maps.Map("#my_Map", {zoom:12, center:latlng, mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP})

marker = new google.maps.Marker({
                map: map,
                position: "Richmond, VA" ,
                title:  "Some title",
              });
map.setCenter("Richmond, VA")
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well you may be okay... Limits to the Google geocoding service are 2500 geocodes per day per ip address.

That means if you're rendering the geocodes client side, you won't need to purchase a Premier license.

It all depends on the app you're building and how you're using these geocodes.

Comment: The unfortunate answer to my question is you can't get around it... we just need to make sure we capture any geocode lookup and save it.

Comment: The terms of service allow you to cache the data for performance reasons for a short period of time.

Comment: That's true, it's actually not a best practice to go back and geocode an address every single time. It's recommend to cache in order to speed things up. As long as your refresh the geocodes 'periodically' (which is the vague language Google gives), it's okay to cache.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the yahoo placefinder, it has an API limit of 50.000 queries a day. If you have more perhaps it's better to cache them?

http://developer.yahoo.com/geo/placefinder/

Comment: 2.5k for non paying users, 100k if you pay for it. http://code.google.com/apis/maps/documentation/geocoding/#Limits

Comment: Premier api only costs 10.000 usd a year. http://www.google.com/enterprise/earthmaps/maps-faq.html

Comment: You have a slight typo... its $10k per year.

Comment: (2.5k hits per day, and 100k per day if you pay 10.000 usd a year, where's the typo?)

Comment: The cost on the site says its $10,000 a year  `Google Maps API Premier is extremely cost-effective, starting at just $10,000 per year. Pricing is based on the number of map page views for externally facing websites. For internal uses, it is based on page views or number of vehicles being tracked. Please contact us for more information. `

Comment: Yes, and those $10k will buy you a 100k hit limit a day.